# AWS Glue - Job Monitoring: Export Information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

On the Job run monitoring page in Glue, there is a table of all job runs which can be generated at different "date range", e.g. 1 day.

How can I export this table or get the same information using SDK without writing code that loops one by one through all glue jobs and their runs?